# form is not valide django

Tags: python, django

when i send data from a post form rzlt always undone ithink it's bcz the form is unvalide

```
def addit(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    target="undone"

    forms = employeeForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
    if forms.is_valid():
        em=models.Employee

        em.fname=forms.cleaned_data["fname"]
        em.cne=forms.cleaned_data["cne"]
        em.lname=forms.cleaned_data["lname"]
        em.division=forms.cleaned_data["division"]
        em.pic=forms.cleaned_data["pic"]
        em.salary=forms.cleaned_data["salary"]
        em.save
        target="done"



return render(request, "home.html",{"target":target} )
```

models

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   fname=models.CharField(max_length=250)
   lname=models.CharField(max_length=250)
   cne=models.CharField(max_length=250)
   division=models.CharField(max_length=250)
   salary=models.FloatField()
   pic=models.FileField(upload_to="static/img")
```

rzl
[hi{{target}}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOToT.png)

Comment: You forget to call the functions.

Comment: But nevertheless you do too much work yourself: the idea is that the form constructs such `Employee`,

Comment: i really don't get it i'm new with django plz more details

Comment: It's `em.save()`, not `em.save`.  
Then why don't you use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) or a [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) ?
And to debug just print the `form.errors`.

Comment: now i get it i'm stpd ty for ur help